# How can i prevent bloc state emit error ("Cannot emit new states after calling close") after widget close?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I open this details page, it calls an API using Bloc and then emits a state. However, when it's in the loading state and before the API call finishes, if I go back to another page, an error occurs. I tried to close Bloc when page get dispose, but the error still persists.

This is my bloc:

```
class DetailsBloc extends Bloc<DetailsEvent, DetailsState> {
  final String id;
  final String server;

  DetailsBloc(this.id, this.server) : super(DetailsLoadingState()) {
    on<DetailsinitEvent>((event, emit) {
      getData(event.id, event.server);
    });
    getData(id, server);
  }
  void getData(String id, String server) async {
    try {
      List res = await Servers(serverID: server, videoID: id).getDetails();
      if (res.isNotEmpty) {
        //emit(DetailsLoadFaildState());
        emit(DetailsLoadedState(res));
      } else {
        emit(DetailsLoadFaildState());
      }
    } catch (_) {
      emit(DetailsLoadFaildState());
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my widget:

```
class Details extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? id;
  final String? server;
  const Details({super.key, required this.id, required this.server});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _Details();
}

class _Details extends State<Details> {
  final bloc = DetailsBloc("", "");
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: AppColors().backgroundColor,
        body: BlocBuilder<DetailsBloc, DetailsState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is DetailsLoadedState) {
              var data = state.data[0];
              // return Container();

              return CustomScrollView(
                physics: const PageScrollPhysics(),
                slivers: [
                  BlocBuilder<DetailsBloc, DetailsState>(
                    builder: (context, state) {
                      return const SliverPadding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(0));
                    },
                  ),
                  SliverList.list(children: [
                    TopSection(
                      data: data["top"],
                      type: data["detailsType"],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 13,
                    )
                  ]),
                ],
              );
            } else if (state is DetailsLoadingState) {
              return const Center(child: LoadingPage());
            } else if (state is DetailsLoadFaildState) {
              return Center(
                  child: ErrorPage(
                page: 'details',
                id: widget.id ?? "",
                server: widget.server,
              ));
            } else {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              return const SliverPadding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(0));
            }
          },
        ));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (!bloc.isClosed) {
      print("object");
      bloc.close();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```